# NAT problem with UFW

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, nat, ufw

I'm trying to setup up an Ubuntu server, and first I want it to act as NAT/router/firewall. **My question is: How do I make it so the computers connected to the LAN, can access Internet?**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:23:87:d3:be
          inet addr:213.101.213.177  Bcast:213.101.213.191  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::21c:23ff:fe87:d3be/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16037 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13626 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2268865 (2.2 MB)  TX bytes:1258854 (1.2 MB)
          Interrupt:26 Base address:0x6000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:21:4f:e4:0b
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21b:21ff:fe4f:e40b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:929 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:309 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:100820 (100.8 KB)  TX bytes:45571 (45.5 KB)
```

eth0 is internet, with dynamic IP. eth1 is LAN.

I've got dhcp-server working, and computers are getting IP addresses. I'm not sure if I've configured it correctly for computers to resolve domain names though.

This is my **dhcpd.conf** file. Notice that I commented out the dns part, as i don't run bind (should I?)

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
option routers 10.0.0.254;
#option domain-name-servers 10.0.0.1;
option domain-name "server.mydomain.com";

subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.200;
}
```

And these are the rules I added to the top of **/etc/ufw/before.rules**

```
# nat Table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Forward traffic from eth1 through eth0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these nat table rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

ufw status: (default is also set to allow)

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   ALLOW       10.0.0.0/24
```

When I try to ping Google from computer 10.0.0.2, I get "destination host unreachable" / "unkown host".

What have I missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router that you've specified in `/etc/dhcpd.conf` is `10.0.0.254`, yet the Ubuntu box you're trying to configure is (apparently) on `10.0.0.1`.

So your client machines' packets aren't even being sent to the Ubuntu box for NAT processing and forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

What is the content for `/etc/resolv.conf` on 10.0.0.2? If no useful *nameserver* is configured, you will not be able to ping by hostname. Either use DHCPD to set the nameserver for all the clients or configure them manually.

If you do not run *bind* you can always use a publicly available DNS server such as the recently launched DNS service by Google. Use `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` nameservers.

Alternatively, if this is a small home/lan setup, you may want to consider using *dnsmasq* instead for your dhcp/dns server. It works as both a DHCP server **and** a DNS server for your local network.

Comment: search server.mydomain.com \n nameserver 10.0.0.1. I ended up installing bind9 (again) and configured dhcpd for it. Got my .2 box to resolve domain names, and Alnitak's answer solved the rest!